# How to Set Servers To My Local TimeZone in Digital Ocean App Platform

Tags: timezone, digital-ocean

Hie,

I have just started using the Digital Ocean App platform to quickly deploy and test our Microservices. One thing that was quickly discovered by our test users was the 2-hour difference in terms of time indicated on some of the messages sent to the customer. We are using CAT / GMT(+2) but the servertime is 2 hours behind. So the question is, how do we change the DO App Platform Servers to Our TimeZone to get the correct time?

Comment: Can't answer about Digital Ocean, but the best practice for dealing with such things is to write your applications such that the server's time zone is irrelevant.  There are many ways to do that, depending on your language/platform.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer from the Digital Ocean Community. The solution to this is to simply add timezone declaration in the environment variables as this: `TZ="Africa/Malawi"` . It works!

Answer (score 0):

I added it to the App-Level Environment Variables under Settings - App and that works. Don't know if that works as well if you add them into the Environment Variables of the component as well?!